# bash until variable equals a number

Tags: bash

I have a simple command which outputs to a text file

```
humidity=$(monitor.txt | grep -m 1 Humidity | cut -d' ' -f2-)
```

but sometimes the output is an error in text a but i want to ignore this and wait for it to be a number ie.

```
until [[ $humudity = [0-9] ]]; then
sleep 1
```

Comment: If you don't reassign the variable, why would sleep change anything?

Comment: `until` should be followed by `do`, not `then`

Comment: Also, use `<monitor.txt grep ...` instead of `monitor.txt | grep ...`; pipes only work if the thing on the left is a command.

Comment: Or just `grep ... monitor.txt`

Comment: And think about reading from a `tail -f` stream instead of `sleep`ing; that way you'll get woken up as soon as there's new content (as long as you deal with buffering appropriately; we have existing answers that help with that).

Comment: using `cat` to read from the same file over and over in a loop is a really bad idea: it means you're reading from the very beginning every time, so you end up reading the same content over (and over, and over); very inefficient -- hence the `tail -f` suggestion; can adjust `tail` to start from the beginning with some appropriate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no example of your `monitor.txt` file, I tried to do mine to test, and there is what I got :

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e
line=1

function check_humidity {
    tail monitor.txt -n +$1 | head -n 1 | grep -m 1 -e '^Humidity [0-9]'
}

until [[ $(check_humidity $line) != "" ]]; do
    line=$(( line + 1 ))
done

echo $(check_humidity $line | cut -d ' ' -f2 -)
# In our case, outputs 209.
```

My `monitor.txt` :

```
InfoA this is an error
InfoB this is another error
InfoC 10
Humidity 209
InfoD this is yet another error
Humidity 100
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) for background on why `set -e`/`bash -e` is a Bad Idea. (Yes, _no error handling at all_ is also a bad idea, but `set -e` is deeply unreliable compared to proper hand-written error handling).

Comment: As for the question, though -- the OP wants to loop until monitor.txt contains a match; I don't see this answer discussing that at all.

Comment: No, Lurch just wants to ge the value of Humidity and the until loop was their first thought. It's wrote nowhere that this person wants to use a loop and read line by line.

Comment: I agree they don't want to read line-by-line (and don't believe I ever said otherwise), but it certainly looks to me even on a reread that they want to keep waiting until humidity data exists in the file, if the content isn't there yet when their script is first invoked. Why would they be asking for an `until` loop otherwise? They already know that `grep` will ignore non-matching lines (such as error messages, assuming an appropriate pattern).

Comment: That is to say, what I was suggesting in question comments to monitor the file until a match existed (if it were still being written) was something like `tail -f -n +0 monitor.txt | grep --line-buffered -m 1 ...` -- you don't need a `while read` loop to get value out of `tail`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is correct I want to wait until the last value of the file is a number as it may contain error 20 error error error 20

Comment: I editted the answer, I would guess that's the result of what you both were talking about then.